# Callng a button made from a for loop from another object's event listener

Tags: actionscript-3, button, for-loop, rollover

I made 2 arrays one for names insect parts, the other for the parts of the insects to show light up.  Rolling over the buttons created by the array and for loop, the parts and buttons light up.  But I also want the parts and buttons to light up when rolling over the insect parts.  My problem is I don't know how to call for the buttons from loop when rolling over the insect parts. See function rollHandler2 and outHandler2.

```
//the arrays look like this...

var parts:Array= [ "Cervical sclerites", "Protonotopleural lobe", "Proepisternum",...]
var shapes:Array = [pt0, pt1, pt2, ...]


for (var i:int = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
    var b:MovieClip = new Btn();
    but.x = 15;
    but.y = ((i)*(b.height+1))+10;
    but.name = "b"+i;
    but.info.text = parts[i];
    but.buttonMode = true;
    but.info.mouseEnabled=false;
    addChild(b);
    but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollHandler);
    but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, outHandler);
    //b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, outHandler);

}

for (var j:int = 0; j < shapes.length; j++){
    shapes[j].buttonMode = true;
    shapes[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollHandler2);
    shapes[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, outHandler2);
}

function rollHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (event.currentTarget.name == "b"+i) {
            this.shapes[i].gotoAndStop("over");
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("over");
        }
    }
}

function outHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (event.currentTarget.name == "b"+i) {
            this.but[i].gotoAndStop("start");
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("start");
        }
    }
}

function rollHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        if (event.currentTarget == shapes[i]) {
            this.parts[i].gotoAndStop("over");
                        //How should i call the button b created from the parts loop?
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("over");
        }
    }
}

function outHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        if (event.currentTarget == shapes[i]) {
            this.b[i].gotoAndStop("start");
                        //same problem here.. Not sure how to call it.
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("start");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code in the question, it is kinda hard to read it like this.

Comment: someone fixed it for you, but for the next time, use a <pre> tag before your you enter your code

Answer (score 1):

I've made some modifications in your code. look at the comment and you should get what i mean. All my comments are marked as this: //---This is an example comment---\\

```
//the arrays look like this...

var parts:Array= [ "Cervical sclerites", "Protonotopleural lobe", "Proepisternum",...];
var shapes:Array = [pt0, pt1, pt2, ...];
var buttons:Array = new Array(); //---Create new array to hold your buttons---\\


for (var i:int = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
    var b:MovieClip = new Btn();
    but.x = 15;
    but.y = ((i)*(b.height+1))+10;
    but.name = "b"+i;
    but.info.text = parts[i];
    but.buttonMode = true;
    but.info.mouseEnabled=false;
    buttons.push(b); //---Push your button into the array each time it loops---\\
    addChild(b);
    but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollHandler);
    but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, outHandler);
    //b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, outHandler);

}

for (var j:int = 0; j < shapes.length; j++){
    shapes[j].buttonMode = true;
    shapes[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollHandler2);
    shapes[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, outHandler2);
}

function rollHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (event.currentTarget.name == "b"+i) {
            this.shapes[i].gotoAndStop("over");
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("over");
        }
    }
}

function outHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (event.currentTarget.name == "b"+i) {
            this.but[i].gotoAndStop("start");
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("start");
        }
    }
}

function rollHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        if (event.currentTarget == shapes[i]) {
            this.parts[i].gotoAndStop("over");
                        //How should i call the button b created from the parts loop?
            buttons[i].gotoAndStop("over"); //---Then you call the button like this at each place.---\\
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("over");
        }
    }
}

function outHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        if (event.currentTarget == shapes[i]) {
            this.b[i].gotoAndStop("start");
                        //same problem here.. Not sure how to call it.
            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("start");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks thought of using the push method too right after posting.  But had some syntax errors and didn't think it would work.  Figured it out and now it works.  Thanks for clarifying that I used it the right way too.

Comment: You're welcome, since this answer is right and it helped you mark it as accepted answer please (green check mark at the top left of my answer).